# I get an error when importing base from deap

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, deap

When I try to import base from deap:

```
from deap import creator, base, tools
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3369 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Input In [2] in <cell line: 1>
    from deap import creator, base, tools

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\deap\base.py:192
    raise TypeError, ("Both weights and assigned values must be a "
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That is the Python 2 syntax, and you're trying to run it under Python 3.  Looks like a bug in the package to me.  You can path this by editing the file and deleting that comma.

Comment: https://github.com/DEAP/deap/pull/591/files#diff-d50863620d1d61c76f24deb3e14f4bd8ce914c860fd8301513d01d37c18fbc1c